# SumProduct over Range that includes text

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to use a sumproduct formula over a range (e.g., A2:B10) given that the corresponding cell in column C = "Mike" - I keep getting #value errors thrown at me because there is text in some cells in the A2:B10 range.

I'm looking for the sum of the numbers(assuming it's a number) in each row with "Mike" in column C.

Formulas I've tried:

- =SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C10="Mike"),A1:B10)
- =SUMPRODUCT((C2:C10="Mike")*(A1:B10))
- =SUMPRODUCT(A1:B10,C2:C10="Mike")

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `=SUMIF(C2:C10,"=Mike",A:A)` Where C is the column of names and A is column of values?

Comment: I don't think SUMIF will work here because the range to sum is two columns while the criteria range is a single column - SUMIF works on a one-to-one basis only - hence my suggestions....you could, of course use two SUMIF functions added together.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this formula with SUMPRODUCT

`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:B10,(C2:C10="Mike")*ISNUMBER(A2:B10))`

or you can use an "array formula"

`=SUM(IF(C2:C10="Mike",A2:B10))`

that latter formula needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> so that curly braces appear around the formula in the formula bar